# Appium Inspector - Call to 'switchContext' failed

Tags: android, angularjs, appium, automation-testing

I am using Appium inspector to find the element path/id/xpath for testing. I am testing hybrid android app. So I try to switch to webview from the dropdown. But I am not able to switch to webview. I am getting following issue.

```
Call to 'switchContext' failed
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '115.0.5790'. See https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md for more details
```

I tried `appium --default-capabilities '{\"appium:chromedriverExecutable\": \"D:\\Projects\\chrome driver\\chromedriver.exe\"}'`

`appium --allow-insecure chromedriver_autodownload`

But still issue is happaning. Please help me on this. I want to get the element path/id/xpath from the webview.

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appium server is need to be updated. After update the Appium server I am able to resolve the issue.

Even after update not working mean then try the following comment to run the Appium server. This comment resolved the issue in another case.

```
appium server --allow-insecure chromedriver_autodownload --base-path /wd/hub
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I rebooted my computer and it went back to normal.